# Are UML class diagrams necessary for designing UIs?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, software-engineering

I want to design UI prototypes and wireframes, based on Use case diagrams, activity diagrams and sequence diagrams to represents the flow and process relation. Is it necessary to include the class diagram in the design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Class diagrams** are for:

a. Describing the low level design of a software component

b. Describing a data model.

**Wireframes** are for designing the interaction and experience of the user with the system. The **use cases** act as input for the wireframes.

The **use cases** can be detailed in text (actors, preconditions, main success scenario, postconditions, branches, exceptions) or in **activity diagrams**.

**Sequence diagrams** show how the use cases are implemented above the classes from the class diagrams and aren't really input for the UI design.

If you want to describe how a custom UI engine works then use class diagrams.

If you want to describe how a user interacts with a UI then use wireframes.

The **class diagrams** are for designing the **implementation** and the **data model**,
 the **wireframes** are for designing the **UX** which (along with the use cases) are a part of the requirements definition which should precede the software design.

When you get to the **UI low level design** - designing the specific fields in a UI, you will want to take into account the UX design (wireframes) and the required data (data model - class diagrams) to make sure the UI is according to the desired experience and that it provides all the required inputs. You may even discover that some of the inputs don't match the desired UX and go back and adjust it e.g. by adding an additional window or control then return to the UI low level design and adjust according to the changes to the wireframe.

Comment: to describe in my world: I would use use case diagrams and activity diagrams to describe user interaction with UI which is an input for the wireframe design. right?

Comment: @user2876656 Yes. Of course there can always be feedback in cases you discover that the inputs need changing (in all stages of design, implementation and testing).

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for your participation. it was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

UML class diagramm isn't *necessary* for the UI design. Though, if it exists, it could be the source for the entities' atributes, which are exist in a domain. So, for example, Author and Book classes have attributes, which could be implemented in a UI. But there is no any data in the diagram which tell you what attributes should be on a form.
[image]

For UI designer who has UML class diagramm only as input spec for an UI, there is a danger of implementing UI, which strictly follows the data model, but brings bad UX. An example is implementing user registration form, which contains all the user profile attributes in the registration form.

So use UML class diagramm as additional source of information, but don't stick with it.

Comment: This is a class diagram which describes the data model which is displayed in the form. You could say it is an input for designing the specific UI for this data once you know that it belongs in a single form.

Comment: I doubt, the author gender will be in a form. Though, you are right, it's a data model which should be *somehow* implemented as a form.

Comment: And using the wireframes you decide if you select an existing author from a list, search for the author using name/email/gender or perhaps you can add a new author without leaving the form.

Comment: @DannyVarod I've edited post ).